# How to save changes by confirming password

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When user updates data on his personal page I want to invoke a confirm dialog with password request to confirm that changes.

Here is my confirm button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Confirm" update="message" ajax="false" actionListener="#{customerBean.confirmChanges()}">
    <p:confirm header="Confirm changes" icon="ui-icon-alert" message="Please enter your password to confirm changes:"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    <p:password value="#{customerBean.currentPassword}" required="true" redisplay="true" label="Current Password"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

And here is the corresponding method:

```
public String confirmChanges() {
    if (currentPassword.equals(customer.getPassword())) {
        saveCustomer();
        logger.info("\nCustomer updating SUCCESS.", " CustomerID:" + customer.getId());
        addMessage("Updating Success", "Your information was successfully updated.", SEVERITY_INFO);
    }
    addMessage("Updating Error", "Your password is wrong please try again.", SEVERITY_ERROR);
    currentPassword = null;
    return null;
}
```

Now when I press the "Submit" button the dialog appears but doesn't invoke my method.

Comment: Do you have a form around it all?

Comment: sure, I have a form around it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml

conform dialog box is used for take yes or no from use, if you want to take value from user better to use dialog box see refer showcase example

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml

This will help you. Use of dialog box is easy.

Comment: thanks, I will try the second example with JavaScript.

Comment: yeah your suggestion was really helpful and now my dialog works as I need!